# How can i create binary persistent connection in c++?

Tags: c++, networking, connection

I want to create persistent TCP connection between two applications in c++. I'm searching for cross-platform solution linux, windows. I heard something about XMPP, but it seems to be using XML for data encapsulation, but i want to travel data in binary form, something like iostream if possible.

How can i create that connection in c++?

Comment: There is no such concept as "server", "client" or "XML" in C++. You have to specify a whole host of platform and protocol details that you have in mind.

Comment: OK. I've specified that. Why that fast downvotes?

Comment: OK, better. TCP connections are usually handled by a "socket" library, which is Berkeley Sockets on Linux and BSD, and WinSock in Windows. The ultimate interface is very similar, though. But all that is very low-level, and perhaps you'd like a high-level wrapper. Boost ASIO comes to mind.

Comment: @MiroK I didn't downvote, but question shows little research.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[beej](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) : Great site on sockets if you want to do it without library. Not too hard to get cross-platform socket code. Winsock is based off BSD sockets. Site lists differences.

[asio](http://think-async.com/) : Great but little documentation. Decent examples.

[ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) : Several books about this one. Looked complex to me several years ago, so I never bother with it personally. Very popular though.

To add to the reasons ( my opinions) to use asio over ACE. ACE has been around a **long** time. Which is great for it stability and it has proven performance. But it was developed when C++ was a much different language than it is now. asio is more modern. It is easier to use if you don't have a background using ACE already.

Answer (score 1):

I would also mention Qt's nice [networking primitives](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qt4-network.html) because it's cross-platform and great to work with. If we assume you wanted to use TCP then you'd create an instance of a [`QTcpServer`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtcpsocket.html), start to listen and accept incoming [`QTcpSocket`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtcpsocket.html) connections. On these you can write binary data as you like (since it inherits from [`QIODevice`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qiodevice.html)) but you could also use serialization implemented by using [`QDataStream`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdatastream.html).